# Laravel Eloquent: Add filter in where (if-else for Conditional Queries)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this code :

```
$result = DB::table('product as p')
      ->join('master as cl', 'p.color', '=', 'cl.name')
      ->join('master as brand', 'p.brand', '=', 'brand.name')
      ->where('p.brand', $brandname)
      ->whereRaw("p.del_flag = 0  and cl.is_active = 1 and brand.is_active = 1 and p.product_type = 1")
      ->select('p.name')
      ->groupBy('p.name')
      ->orderBy('p.name')
      ->take(3)
      ->get();
```

I need add filters:

```
if(isset($_POST['brand'])) {
    ->where('p.brand', $_POST['brand'])
}
if(isset($_POST['color'])) {
    ->where('p.color', $_POST['color'])
}
if(isset($_POST['product_type'])) {
    ->where('p.product_type', $_POST['product_type'])
}
```

I've seen a lot of posts regarding multiple Where in laravel but not a single one talking about those special wheres.

how to add filter in query?

Comment: Try this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First pass the query to a variable and update the query variable.

```
$query = DB::table('product as p')
      ->join('master as cl', 'p.color', '=', 'cl.name')
      ->join('master as brand', 'p.brand', '=', 'brand.name')
      ->where('p.brand', $brandname)
      ->whereRaw("p.del_flag = 0  and cl.is_active = 1 and brand.is_active = 1 and p.product_type = 1")
      ->select('p.name')
      ->groupBy('p.name')
      ->orderBy('p.name')
      ->take(3);

if( isset($_POST['brand'])) {
    $query->where('p.brand', $_POST['brand'])
}
if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
    $query->where('p.color', $_POST['color'])
}
if (isset($_POST['product_type'])) {
    $query->where('p.product_type', $_POST['product_type'])
}

$result = $query->get();
```

---

**Update:**
As @Amol Rokade mentioned, you can also use the [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses) function:

```
$result = DB::table('product as p')
      ->join('master as cl', 'p.color', '=', 'cl.name')
      ->join('master as brand', 'p.brand', '=', 'brand.name')
      ->where('p.brand', $brandname)
      ->whereRaw("p.del_flag = 0  and cl.is_active = 1 and brand.is_active = 1 and p.product_type = 1")
      ->when(isset($_POST['brand']), function ($query) {
            $query->where('p.brand', $_POST['brand']);
      })
      ->when(isset($_POST['color']), function ($query) {
            $query->where('p.color', $_POST['color']);
      })
      ->when(isset($_POST['product_type']), function ($query) {
            $query->where('p.product_type', $_POST['product_type']);
      })
      ->select('p.name')
      ->groupBy('p.name')
      ->orderBy('p.name')
      ->take(3)
      ->get();
```

Comment: Instead of above, can we use this one https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = DB::table('product as p')
  ->join('master as cl', 'p.color', '=', 'cl.name')
  ->join('master as brand', 'p.brand', '=', 'brand.name')
  ->where(function($query) use ($brandname,$_POST){
      $query->where('p.brand', $brandname);
      $query->whereRaw("p.del_flag = 0  and cl.is_active = 1 and brand.is_active = 1 and p.product_type = 1");

      if( isset($_POST['brand'])) {
         $query->where('p.brand', $_POST['brand']);
      }
      if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
         $query->where('p.color', $_POST['color']);
      }
      if (isset($_POST['product_type'])) {
         $query->where('p.product_type', $_POST['product_type']);
      }
  })
  ->select('p.name')
  ->groupBy('p.name')
  ->orderBy('p.name')
  ->take(3);
  ->get();
```

**Hope this will help you**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add filter in query you can do that by create query object something like that

```
$result = DB::table('product as p')
      ->join('master as cl', 'p.color', '=', 'cl.name')
      ->join('master as brand', 'p.brand', '=', 'brand.name')
      ->where('p.brand', $brandname)
      ->whereRaw("p.del_flag = 0  and cl.is_active = 1 and brand.is_active = 1 and p.product_type = 1")
      ->select('p.name')
      ->groupBy('p.name')
      ->orderBy('p.name');


if(isset($_POST['brand'])) {
    $result->where('p.brand', $_POST['brand'])
}
if(isset($_POST['color'])) {
    $result->where('p.color', $_POST['color'])
}
if(isset($_POST['product_type'])) {
    $result->where('p.product_type', $_POST['product_type'])
}

$result->take(3)->get();
```

that will do the trick .

Answer (score 0):

My last code:

```
$querydata = DB::table('product as p')
  ->join('master as cl', 'p.color', '=', 'cl.name')
  ->join('master as brand', 'p.brand', '=', 'brand.name')
  ->where('p.brand', $brandname)
  ->whereRaw("p.del_flag = 0  and cl.is_active = 1 and brand.is_active = 1 and p.product_type = 1")
  ->select('p.name')
  ->groupBy('p.name')
  ->orderBy('p.name')
  ->take(3);



  if(!empty($_POST)) {
      unset($_POST['_token']);

  foreach ($_POST as $column => $data) {
    if(empty($data)) {
      continue;
    }

    if(is_array($data)) {

      $querydata = $querydata->where(function($query) use ($column, $data) {
          foreach ($data as $value) {
            $query->orWhere('p.'.$column, $value);
          }
      });
    } else {
      $querydata->where('p.'.$column, $data);
    }

  }


 }

  $result = $querydata->get();
```

I hope to help somebody.